# Check if current branch is in newline delimited list

Tags: scripting, git

I am trying to create a git pre-commit hook. If the current branch is already merged with the integration branch, I don't want to allow new commits to that branch. I have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

git fetch origin dev
current_branch=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
branches="$(git branch --merged dev | tr '@squashed' '')"
```

say I have these two branches:

```
me/feature/x
me/feature/x@squashed
```

What I want to do is replace '@squashed', so I get this:

```
me/feature/x
me/feature/x
```

then if the current branch starts with either of those names, then exit with code 1.

The problem is:

1. I can't figure out how to use tr/sed to only replace '@squashed' if the branch name ends with that string.
2. I can't figure out how to loop over the elements and exit with non-zero if the current branch starts with one of the branch names in the list.

Comment: would it make more sense to assign the output of `git branch` to an array than a scalar?  Bash also has some amount of variable expansion capabilities, where you can replace text in variables.

Answer (score 2):

1. `tr` replaces single characters, not strings. As you surmise you can use `sed` to delete a string at the end of a line:

   ```
   git branch --merged dev | sed 's/@squashed$//'
   ```
2. Instead of looping, use `grep` to determine whether a list of strings, one per line, contains a line starting with a reference string:

   ```
   git branch --merged dev | sed 's/@squashed$//' | grep -q "^..$current_branch"
   ```

Better yet, since you’re using `git`, ask it to filter for you:

```
git branch --list "${current_branch}*" --merged dev
```

will list any branch merged with `dev` whose name starts with the current branch. (Since you’re filtering by matching the start of branch names, you don’t need to drop the “@squashed” part, unless I’m missing something.)